# How to determine the SATA port revision?

Tags: sata, optical-drive, dell-studio

I saw [this product](http://www.pro-battery.com/battery-detail.asp?id=627) advertised at various places on the internet; it's a 2.5" HDD caddy to replace the optical drive in laptops. My question is, how to find out if the DVD drive has a SATA II or III interface? My laptop is a Dell Studio 1558.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SATA-II and SATA-III are compatible, and you are unlikely to see any difference in performance between the two on a laptop HDD.

So the basic answer would be: do not hesitate to buy this product, it will work for your laptop.

Answer (score 2):

That laptop, according to a Google search, was released mid-2010, and I believe that the first Sata III equipped laptops came out in late 2010 - early 2011. I think Intel's Sandy Bridge chipset was the first to support it natively.

If you want to investigate for yourself, you can try use [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy).

Sata II and III are compatible either way, similar (practically speaking) to the USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports